# Rear shock mounting hardware for Felt Virtue 2015

Tags: frames

I recently bought a Felt Virtue 2015 aluminum frame. Just wondering if anyone else who bought the same frame have the correct sizing for the rear shock mounting hardware.

For reference this is the frame I bought https://www.chainreactioncycles.com/ca/en/felt-virtue-al-29-full-suspension-frame-2015/rp-prod187393

Comment: Are you asking what size bolts / pins are required for fitting the rear shock, or what size rear shock to fit? From what I can find the bike would have come fitted with a Rockshock RT.

Comment: Yeah I am planning on also using Rockshox RT, but the mounting hardware is a bit tricky

Comment: You will need to measure the eyelet with calipers or a decent ruler to work out what size collar and bushes you need. Common sizes are 12.7mm and 12mm, some older shocks were 10mm. The collar or pin you get will decide if it's fixed with an M6, M8 or M10 nut and bolt.

Comment: I did a couple of measurments and it seems like 28.6x6. For rockshox it would most likely be 1/2 x 1/2 and 28.6mm x 6mm